# After Effects music equalizer freeze

Tags: after-effects

I have been using After Effects and I own a YouTube channel which is like "Trap nation". One problem though, sometimes after a certain time period, the animation freezes. If you see this video

[The equalizer animation freezes after one minute.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHgWGPjP0sc)

Thanks guys for helping me with this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the equalizer effect you made runs through to the end of the song you are using. If that is not the case, just stretch the animation to the end of the song and you should be good to go.

If that does not work, create a new project or sequence and import your current files to the new project.

Comment: I tried the first two things you have suggested but it didn't! Thanks but sorry that didn't work!

Comment: Share some screenshots of your AE project - make sure we can see any keyframes on the tracks - you might get a better answer